# Disable Polymer on Youtube

Tags: youtube, google-chrome, userscripts, greasemonkey

Ever since Youtube got rid of the option to revert to the old site I've had a script for Violent Monkey to switch to the old Youtube. Today when I went to Youtube I discovered that that script is no longer working. However, adding **?disable_polymer=true** still reverts Youtube to the old Youtube. It's still there and can still be accessed, so what will fix my script to get it working again so I can keep using old Youtube?

This is the script currently.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Youtube - Restore Classic
// @version      1.0.9
// @description  If youtube is in the new 2017 YouTube Material Redesign, automatically restore classic view
// @author       Cpt_mathix
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
// @exclude      https://www.youtube.com/tv*
// @exclude      https://www.youtube.com/embed/*
// @exclude      https://www.youtube.com/live_chat*
// @license      GPL-2.0+; http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
// @namespace    https://greasyfork.org/users/16080
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        none
// @noframes
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    init();

    document.addEventListener("spfdone", function(e) {
        document.getElementById("content").classList.add("content-alignment");
        document.getElementById("body").classList.remove("sitewide-ticker-visible");
    });

    function init() {
        restoreClassicYoutube();
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            hideNewYoutubeBanner();
        }, false);
    }

    function restoreClassicYoutube() {
        // Cookies are enabled?
        if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
            if (document.cookie) {
                var cookie = getCookie("PREF");

                // Pref cookie exists?
                if (cookie) {
                    console.log("current PREF cookie: " + cookie);
                    if (cookie.search(/f6=(8|9)(&|;|$)/) === -1) {
                        replaceCookieAndReload(cookie);
                    } else {
                        deleteCache("reloadCount");
                    }
                } else {
                    createCookieAndReload();
                }
            } else {
                createCookieAndReload();
            }
        } else {
            console.log("Error: Youtube - Restore Classic doesn't work if cookies are disabled");
        }
    }

    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookie = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(name + '=([^;]+)'));
        if (cookie && cookie[1]) {
            return cookie[1];
        }
        return null;
    }

    function createCookieAndReload() {
        document.cookie = "PREF=f6=8;path=/;domain=.youtube.com";
        reload();
    }

    function replaceCookieAndReload(cookie) {
        if (cookie.search(/f6=[^;&]*/) === -1) {
            document.cookie = "PREF=" + cookie + "&f6=8;path=/;domain=.youtube.com";
        } else if (cookie.search(/f6=[^;&]*/) !== -1) {
            document.cookie = "PREF=" + cookie.replace(/f6=[^;&]*/, 'f6=8') + ";path=/;domain=.youtube.com";
        }
        reload();
    }

    function reload() {
        var reloadCount = getCache("reloadCount");
        if (reloadCount && parseInt(reloadCount) <= 3) {
            setCache("reloadCount", parseInt(reloadCount) + 1);
            location.reload();
        } else if (reloadCount && parseInt(reloadCount) > 3) {
            console.log("Youtube - Restore Classic\nSomething went wrong... Please post the following information on greasyfork and disable this script\n\nDebug information:\nCookies enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "\nCurrent cookies: " + getCookie("PREF"));
            deleteCache("reloadCount");
        } else {
            setCache("reloadCount", 1);
            location.reload();
        }
    }

    function getCache(key) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("YTRestore#" + key));
    }

    function deleteCache(key) {
        localStorage.removeItem("YTRestore#" + key);
    }

    function setCache(key, value) {
        localStorage.setItem("YTRestore#" + key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }

    function hideNewYoutubeBanner() {
        document.getElementById("content").classList.add("content-alignment");
        document.getElementById("body").classList.remove("sitewide-ticker-visible");

        var css = `
#ticker {
    display: none!important;
}
`;

        var style = document.createElement("style");
        style.type = "text/css";
        if (style.styleSheet){
            style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
        } else {
            style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
        }

        document.documentElement.appendChild(style);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Here are a coupe of useful posts pertaining to this problem on the /r/youtube subreddit: https://redd.it/ha0gan, https://redd.it/h9zldf

Comment: @GDP2 I've looked at the links you provided and I've tried the new script. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, it worked for me. I guess you can contact the guy who made the script at the second link and see if he can help you. You'll want to make sure you do the user-agent switching stuff mentioned in the first link too. Also, I've still noticed some glitches myself, like the `Read More` button doesn't work. There are apparently some solutions in the comments, but I haven't tried them out yet.